# Error passing parameters in Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to use SSDT to deploy a report that will allow for the input of 2 parameters that I can use for the start and the end of a log file. My parameters are declared as DateTime under the Parameters dropdown under Report Data. The Dataset has the Parameters included in it's properties as well. This is my SQL statement and error.

```
[Declare] @StartTime DateTime 
[Declare] @EndTime Datetime 
SELECT RecordID, AnalysisID, HeatName, NewHeatName, AnalysisTime, SampleType, Grade, NewGrade, ProductID, RecordChangeTime, ChangesMade, LoggedUser
FROM Chemistry_Log
WHERE (RecordChangeTime >= @ StartTime) AND (RecordChangeTime <= @ EndTime)
```

The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:

Unable to parse query text.

I'm not sure where to go from here, because that isn't very informative of an error message...

Comment: can you show you variables declaration ? this is probably where the problem is

Comment: This is my entire query... I've never created a report before so I'm learning. So I'm guessing my variables need a declaration then? How should I go about doing that?

Comment: look at my answer. I'll update it with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks correct. I don't think the problem is there. Are the parameters defined in the report? That is, are they showing up in the parameters section of the report items? are they defined in the properties of the dataset as well? Normally these should pick up any undeclared paramters automatically, but I've seen times where the automatic creation doesn't work.

I you see the parameters in your report definition, make sure they are set to be DateTime parameters. Also, don't leave them blank when running the sample query: supply a valid date value. Even when you click OK, and the prompt comes up asking for parameter values. Just fill in any valid date: SSRS sometimes needs this to run the query once and determine the columns that will be returned by the query.

Comment: I think technically I'm using SSDT, but its pretty much the same thing. I can run the report without parameters, but once I put the parameters in, I have a problem. I have the parameters declared under the Parameters dropdown in the Report Data window... they're also specified as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to parse query text

Your query *should* be working with the provided information. The only missing part is your [variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) declaration. In this case, I don't see :

```
Declare @StartTime DateTime 
Declare @EndTime   Datetime
```

This will declare to variables ready to store a `DateTime`. As for how you assign the values to the variables it all depends on what you are going to do with your query.

- Use it in a [Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- Call your query directly in your database management system
- Call it from an application and pass them as [Sql Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

You did not provide enough information for me to go in more details.

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me the error: Unable to parse query text. It gives me no more information... Any ideas? It still asks me to declare the variable "@". Would it make a difference that I'm using an ODBC?

Comment: What, where, how, when are you using this query ?

Comment: You should read about variables in the link I provide. They are not initialised in the example I gave to you so they are null. Read the article and if you need more help afterward provide more information about where you're using this query

Comment: I am using this query to create a report. The original report has everything besides the WHERE statement. But now I'm trying to make the report narrow down the results based on these two DateTimes. I'm trying to use these two parameters for a report that will be put on Sharepoint. Does this help?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question "what am I using this query" but I'm using it now... I hope my last post cleared things up. I looked through the MSDN but to be honest, that doesn't really seem to make anything any more clear for me. This issue really doesn't look to be very complicated to me, but I guess that's why I can't figure it out either...

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk For SSRS queries, variable don't need to be declared if they will be provided by as SSRS parameters. SSRS will take care of that.